# Why is Spotlight indexing taking so long when I only have Applications and System Preferences checked?

Tags: spotlight

I narrowed the scope of Spotlight to just Applications and System Preferences, but the indexing is still taking seemingly forever and not just after restart. Any idea what could be going on? I know I can stop it by removing my disk from scope, but I'm looking for a middle ground.

Here are the results of `mdutil -sav`:

```
/:
    Indexing enabled.
/System/Volumes/Data:
    Indexing enabled.
/Volumes/GoogleDrive:
    Indexing and searching disabled.
    enter code here
```

Comment: I have no evidence to back this up, but it wouldn't surprise me if it still indexed everything, but just restricted the results it shows.

Comment: Can you show the output from the Terminal command `mdutil -sav`.

Comment: @Gilby See updated question.

Comment: Look good for first two volumes, except: with the `v` in `mdutil -sav`, there should be (for each volume) a 3rd line saying about 'Scan base time'. The lack of that suggests that the indexing has not completed. But I guess you know that. I am bit worried about the 'enter code here' - I have never seen that before. Maybe @Tetsujin knows.